# Analyze output of openssl ciphers with haproxy default ciphers configuration

Tags: openssl

I am trying to analyze the different cryptographic algorithms used by the default haproxy configuration in an audit purpose as it obviously contains some deprecated stuff in it. The configuration line is:

```
ssl-default-bind-ciphers  !SSLv2:kEECDH:kRSA:kEDH:kPSK:+3DES:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5:!EXP:!RC4:!SEED:!IDEA:!DES
```

I use OpenSSL to expend the algorithms list `openssl ciphers '$list_here'`:

Among all i obtain, I get the following algorithms which looks weird to me:

```
AES128-GCM-SHA256
AES128-SHA256
AES128-SHA
DES-CBC3-SHA
```

Usually, cryptographic algorithms comply with the format :

```
KeyExchangeAlgo - AuthenticationAlgo - EncryptionAlgo - IntegrityCheckAlgo
```

From what I know, AES is not a key exchange algorithms, and neither is DES; Hence which kind of algorithms is used to perform this task ? And it can't be none as i obtain the very same list when i add `!kNULL` to the command!

Furthermore, the haproxy configuration line explicitly disables the DES algorithm; however, it is getting expended by the openssl command:

```
DES-CBC3-SHA
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: (k)EECDH means ephemeral elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman. (k)EDH is plain ephemeral Diffie-Hellman. And (k)PSK is pre shared key. As for the cipher list, AES128-GCM is AES in the authenticated GCM block cipher mode. I assume plain AES128 means CTR mode, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OpenSSL uses different ciphersuite names than the standard ones in the RFCs** and many (most?) other implementations, excepting the recently added and differently structured TLS1.3 'suites'. See the man page for `ciphers` on your system [or on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ciphers.html) at the heading 'CIPHER SUITE NAMES' about halfway down and/or my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463429/map-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-and-their-openssl-equivalents for the forward algorithm. Going in reverse for your values:

```
AES128-GCM-SHA256 = TLS_RSA_WITH_AES128_GCM_SHA256 (omit TLS WITH always, RSA for akRSA)
AES128-SHA256     = TLS_RSA_WITH_AES128_CBC_SHA256 (same and omit CBC sometimes)
AES128-SHA        = TLS_RSA_WITH_AES128_CBC_SHA (ditto)
DES-CBC3-SHA      = TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (same and swap 3DES_EDE_CBC to DES-CBC3; the 3 means triple-DES)
```

> Furthermore, the haproxy configuration line explicitly disables the DES algorithm; however, it is getting expended by the openssl command: DES-CBC3-SHA

(Nit: you mean expand ... and expanded; expend[ed] means 'used up', like money that has been spent or a bomb that has exploded.)

OpenSSL considers original/single DES and triple-DES different algorithms. That cipherstring disables single-DES, but not triple-DES; in fact the `+3DES` explicitly *adds* triple-DES algorithms at the end of the list, thus with lower priority *if* you use server priority. Similarly, you can select AES128 suites separately from AES256 suites even though both use the AES algorithm; in that case there is also an option 'AES' that selects both groups.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, and for helping improving my English :)